# Is the stabilizer of an irreducible subvariety of an abelian variety irreducible ?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $A$ be a (semi-)abelian variety over an algebraically closed field $K$, and $X$ be a closed irreducible subvariety. Can $X$ have a non-trivial finite stabilizer ? By stabilizer, I mean the closed subgroup $S\subset A$ such that $X$ is stable by translation by any point in $S$.
This question is equivalent to the one in the title since you can always take the quotient by the neutral component of $S$ to reduce to a finite group.

Comment: No. Let $f:A \to B$ be a separable isogeny and $D$ a smooth ample divisor in $B$. Then $f^{−1}(D)$ is irreducible if $\dim(X)>1$ (since it is smooth and connected) and is stabilized by the kernel of $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take a curve in its Jacobian and pull it back by multiplication by some n. The resulting pullback is a curve invariant by the n torsion.